# Delaying a task for a very very long time

Tags: c#, .net-core

If we delay a Task using the `Task.Delay` method for a very long time, let's say 6 months, and if we assume that the OS does not shutdown or restart during this period of time, is there any guarantee the associated Task would wake up at the right time? Or will it be killed by the OS?

Comment: If you want something robust, sounds like you'll want a task scheduler like Windows's Scheduled Tasks or Linux's systemd timers or cron instead.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: It's a theoretical question.

Comment: `Task.Delay` will only work for up to 24 days

Comment: @DavidG: Is there any documentation that describes it?

Comment: Yes, the official docs... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: @DavidG: Thank's Dave.

Comment: David, there's no Dave here :)

Comment: @DavidG: Sorry Dave, I meant David :D

Comment: Right, to be specific the maximum is 2147483647 (2^31-1) milliseconds, i.e. about 24.855 days.

Comment: @DavidG while we're being precise.. "up to 24 days" is floored/might be better expressed as 24.86 etc.. ? :D

Comment: @CaiusJard: Yeah, the limit is the max value of Int32 apparently.

Comment: @Camilo someone who'd never heard of windows task scheduler ? :)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: Absolutely, I asked the question because it also take a `TimeSpan` as argument.

Comment: @CaiusJard Yes you are right, but what if he wants to run his app with mono on linux? but otherwise good impact

Comment: @ArnoldZahrneinder but you can also create a thread that can own a list with tasks. Which it always scans once per day, so this thread is mostly in sleep and consumes "nothing". For this you could save these tasks and load them (if the system would crash).

Comment: Blast from the past.. so, Linux doesn't have a task scheduler? The "also" option sounds a bit like reinventing the HangFire wheel..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `Task.Delay` for that length of time. The [method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay?view=netcore-3.1) takes an `int` number of milliseconds, meaning the maximum number you can pass in is `int.MaxValue`. That translates to approximately 24.86 days.

The overload that takes a `TimeSpan` is also restricted according to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay?view=netcore-3.1#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_Delay_System_TimeSpan_):

> *Exception*: The `delay` argument's [`TotalMilliseconds`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.totalmilliseconds?view=netcore-3.1#System_TimeSpan_TotalMilliseconds) property is greater than [`MaxValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.maxvalue?view=netcore-3.1).

If you want a task to happen after a longer period, there are far better tools for that, such as [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/) or even the operating system task scheduler.